# Compute topological invariants of graph

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

Consider a rigid loop shown above. Three elastic ropes are tied to the loop so that their ends can slide along the loop. But two ends cannot cross each other. So basically there are two non-equivalent ways, namely, two configurations are not homeomorphic.

My question is, how can one differentiate two cases? I tried considering computing homology groups and relative (rel loop) homology groups but that didn't work. I am not familiar with  relative homotopy so not sure whether it helps.

Comment: I am not sure about the solution of the question, the two graphs above all homotopy to the wedge sum of four circles, why they are different?

Comment: @yili it is assumed that loop is rigid and ends of ropes cannot slide across each other. In another word, I care about homeomophism, not homotopy.

Comment: It's unclear what the question really is. What do you mean by "differentiate"? You have two topological spaces which are obviously non-homeomorphic but homotopy-equivalent. What is the equivalence relation you are interested in?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I want to find some computable topological invariants which can be used to prove they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @MoisheKohan One more question, are they still homotopic relative the loop?

Comment: I do not understand what a "computable invariant" means. One can easily prove that the spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: What does "homotopic relative to" mean? Do you mean, "relatively homotopy-equivalent"? I am sure that they are not, but it requires some thought. I suggest, you edit your post to clarify the question.

Comment: @MoisheKohan "computable" means one can writes a program to compute, for example, simplicial homology group.

Comment: @zhangwfjh: What do you mean by "an invariant"?

Comment: @MoisheKohan "invariant" means algebraic objects that keep the same under "slide"

Comment: @MoisheKohan how do you actually show that they are not homeomorphic? It doesn't look easy to me.

Comment: @freakish for example in the space on the left you can remove two points and get three connected components two if which have nontrivial fundamental group. In the space on the right whenever you remove two points that disconnect the space in three components, two of those have trivial fundamental group

Comment: There is a simple and complete topological invariant, but I don't think it will be very satisfying to you. Enumerate the set of vertices of valence not equal to $2$, $V = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$. Form the $n \times n$ matrix $M$ whose entry $m_{ij}$ is equal to the number of "natural" edges of the graph such that one end is attached to $v_i$ and the other end is attached to $v_j$ (a "natural" edge is a component of the complement of $V$).

Comment: The matrix $M$ determines the topology of the graph, but the topology of the graph does not quite yet determine $M$, because of the choice of enumeration of the vertex set. To correct for that, define an equivalence relation on $n \times n$ matrices where $M \sim M'$ if and only if there exists an $n \times n$ permutation matrix $B$ such that $M' = B M B^{-1}$. The equivalence class $[M]$ is a complete invariant of the topology of the graph.

Comment: @LeeMosher Did you imply that regard adjacent matrix of graph as topology invariant? How to handle cyclic property? I mean, if $B$ is a permutation, i.e. a relabling. Then two graphs above are the same, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable intuition for what I wrote: two graphs are the same if they have the same adjacency matrix up to relabelling. The effect of conjugating the adjacency matrix $M$ by the permutation matrix $B$ is to convert $M$ into the adjacency matrix or the permuted labelling.